# How can i get updates of carrier detaction in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How can i get updates of carrier detaction in iphone sdk? I need to show its status when i am in coverage area or not. Not want to check whether it is connected with internet or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following from [source](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299)

> Even though Apple provides sample code for monitoring changes in
>   network availability, Apple's Reachability class is a bit outdated and
>   doesn't support ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). If you use
>   `AFNetworking`, then you may want to consider AFHTTPClient, which also
>   lets you monitor network interface changes.
>
> However, my preferred solution is the wonderful Reachability class
>   created and maintained by [Tony Million](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability). It supports ARC and leverages
>   GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).